# After a horse's owner is dead, is it still a crime to take his horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If the owner of a horse(NPC) dies, and is horse is roaming around, can you take it, or will it still be stealing?

If it is stealing, is there any way to make the horse yours if the original owner is dead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it will not be stealing (you can verify this by simply mousing over the horse - "steal horse" should not appear), and this "loss-of-ownership" has a tendency to happen a lot for random encounter NPCs such as "Hunter" and "Poacher".

The one caveat is that such a claimed horse, though it will show up whenever you fast travel, shows a blatant disregard towards you as a potential owner, and upon dismounting, will immediately set foot for where you originally found them.

"Wild" horses like this are irksome to keep track of, and usually its better to just shell out the 1,000 septims for a mount who won't snub you every time you stop to enter a cave.

Comment: Unless you blow in their Ear : p  right Raven lol

Comment: Hmm weird I never have the Steal Horse thing disapear :(

Answer (score 0):

Stolen yes, bounty no, there has to be witnesses for a bounty. There are three obtainable free horses, Shadowmere obtainable in the dark brotherhood, frost obtainable by talking with Louis Letrush in riften, and if you have dawngaurd, the invincible horse aravak is found wandering the soul Carin.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is stealing. if you look at the horse it will say "Steal horse"
and unless you bought the horse before I don't think you can take it without stealing.
What you can do is, get/buy a different horse, steal it when no ones looking or Get frost (white horse with extra stamina)